# Disable logging in gunicorn for a specific request / URL / endpoint

Tags: python, logging, flask, gunicorn

Recently, there was the question of how to disable logging in Python Flask for a specific endpoint ([Skip Flask logging for one endpoint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56959585/skip-flask-logging-for-one-endpoint/57413338)).

This makes sense for example for `/healthcheck` which you don't want to clutter your logs.

I solved this for Flask, but when running Flask using Gunicorn my solution doesn't work anymore.

How do I achieve this using Gunicorn? I want regular logging behavior, but not have any logs for the `/healthcheck` endpoint.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I figured it out - you need to override the `pre_request` hook.

This can be done as follows:

You need to create a config file, e.g. `config/gunicorn.py`:

```
def pre_request(worker, req):
    if req.path == '/healthcheck':
        return
    worker.log.debug("%s %s" % (req.method, req.path))
```

And then use it when you start gunicorn:
`gunicorn server:app -c config/gunicorn.py`

Comment: The solution works, but is this documented and can you point to the documentation that specifies this method?

Comment: https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#server-hooks

Answer (score 11):

The `pre_request` hook wasn't working for me. I used the answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/52455408/2339067 to create the following `gunicorn.conf.py` file:

```
import logging
from gunicorn import glogging


class CustomGunicornLogger(glogging.Logger):

    def setup(self, cfg):
        super().setup(cfg)

        # Add filters to Gunicorn logger
        logger = logging.getLogger("gunicorn.access")
        logger.addFilter(HealthCheckFilter())

class HealthCheckFilter(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, record):
        return 'GET /healthcheck' not in record.getMessage()

accesslog = '-'
logger_class = CustomGunicornLogger
```

Comment: Checking if  '/healthceck' not in record.args also works.

Comment: Filtering should never be done on `record.getMessage()`. This means that by appropriately setting their user agent, attackers can avoid their requests being logged. Plus it's unecessary work for creating a message that will be discarded.