# Disable logging in gunicorn with Django for a specific request/URL/endpoint

Tags: django, gunicorn

This question is similar to [Disable logging in gunicorn for a specific request / URL / endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57416645/disable-logging-in-gunicorn-for-a-specific-request-url-endpoint) except that my question is concerned with disabling gunicorn healthcheck logging in a Django app.

How do I disable gunicorn logging in a Django app?

I'm also using syslog, so the `settings.LOGGING` dictionary is something like this:

```
LOGGING = {
    "version": 1,
    "disable_existing_loggers": False, 
    "handlers": {
        "console": {
            "level": "DEBUG",
            "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
            "formatter": "default",
        }, 
        "syslog": {
            "level": "DEBUG",
            "class": "logging.handlers.SysLogHandler",
            "formatter": "default",
            "facility": SysLogHandler.LOG_LOCAL2,
            "address": syslog_address,
        },
    },
    "loggers": {
        "django": {"handlers": ["console", "syslog"], "propagate": True},
        "apps": {"handlers": ["console", "syslog"], "level": "DEBUG"},
        "utils": {"handlers": ["console", "syslog"], "level": "DEBUG"}, 
        "gunicorn.access": {"handlers": ["console", "syslog"], "level": "INFO"},
        "gunicorn.error": {"handlers": ["console", "syslog"], "level": "INFO"},
    },
}
```

Note that I explicitly added the `gunicorn.access` logger for use with syslog (see: https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/issues/2016).

Answer (score 3):

I'm answering my own question.

Once I added the `gunicorn.access` logger to deal with `syslog`, I could not simply add a `pre_request` hook in my `gunicorn.conf` file (as per [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57416645/disable-logging-in-gunicorn-for-a-specific-request-url-endpoint)).

You have to provide your own custom logging class by subclassing `gunicorn.glogging.Logger` as stated in the [docs](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#logger-class).

Create a logging module and add:

```
from gunicorn import glogging
class CustomGunicornLogger(glogging.Logger):
    def access(self, resp, req, environ, request_time):
        # disable healthcheck logging
        if req.path in ["/healthcheck"]:
            return
        super().access(resp, req, environ, request_time)
```

In your `gunicorn.conf` file, add:

```
logger_class = 'your_module.CustomGunicornLogger'
```

Use your `gunicorn.conf` file when using gunicorn:

```
gunicorn --config=gunicorn.conf your_django_app.wsgi:application
```

Answer (score 3):

Another solution was inspired by this `gunicorn` answer: [How to filter logs from gunicorn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52407736/how-to-filter-logs-from-gunicorn)

```
class HealthCheckFilter(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, record):
        return record.getMessage().find('/healthcheck') == -1
```

Add the healthcheck to the custom logger:

```
class CustomGunicornLogger(glogging.Logger):
    def setup(self, cfg):
        super().setup(cfg)

        # Add filters to Gunicorn logger
        logger = logging.getLogger("gunicorn.access")
        logger.addFilter(HealthCheckFilter())
```