# How to disable console log for a specific url in django?

Tags: django, kubernetes

My view is below

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def get_test(request):
    return HttpResponse('Ok', status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

and my path in urls.py in urlpatterns is as below.

```
path('api/test', views.get_test),
```

EDIT:- I did not ask the right question before. I keep getting "[DEBUG] GET /api/test" in the console every 3 seconds because of the liveness probe and I need to disable the console log for this endpoint.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable logging in gunicorn with Django for a specific request/URL/endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58816316/disable-logging-in-gunicorn-with-django-for-a-specific-request-url-endpoint)

Answer (score 1):

One way to do that is to create a separate logger with that level. In your `settings.py`:

```py
LOGGING = {
    "version": 1,
    "disable_existing_loggers": False,
    "loggers": {
        "": {
            "level": "ERROR",
        },
        "critical_only": {
            "level": "CRITICAL",
        },
    },
}
```

Then in your critical-only view you can use that logger, e.g.:

```py
critical_only_logger = logging.getLogger("critical_only")
critical_only_logger.error("error")
```

The last line above will not print, as expected. For the other, "normal" logger you can do the usual `logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)` in other views where you might need more details.

To disable logging, just do that at the top of your view: `logging.disable(logging.CRITICAL)`

Comment: thanks for your answer but i think i asked the wrong question. So, what i want is the url being called not to show up in the console. I keep getting "[DEBUG] GET /api/test" in the console. Is there a way to disable this?

Comment: I'm a bit confused, but some combination of logger config should do the trick for you. If you need to disable those "GET /" logs from `django.server`, you can create a "django.server" logger and send its output to null (in your settings logger section). All other loggers you define, including the default one, will still work.

Comment: I think you are on the right path, but how to disable those "GET /" logs for a specific url? that is the part i am having trouble with. I want the console logs for all other urls to show up. I found a gunicorn solution for this but was wondering if there is a django solution for it.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Django's documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/logging/#django-server), the logger `django.server` is responsible for logging messages related to the handling of requests received by the server invoked by the runserver command. Therefore, we can attach to it a filter that will block logging messages related to a specific URL.

This filter will do the job for your question example:

```py
class IgnoreApiTest:
    def filter(self, record):
        if "api/test" in record.getMessage():
            return False
        else:
            return True
```

The `filter` method should return `True` if the message is to be logged and `False` otherwise. You can find more about filters in Python’s built-in [logging module docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#), which is the logging system Django uses.

Assuming `mysite` is the project directory, and that `IgnoreApiTest` is defined inside the file `mysite/filters.py`, we can add this filter to `django.server` logger in the file `mysite/mysite/settings.py`:

```py
import logging
from filters import IgnoreApiTest

logging.getLogger("django.server").addFilter(IgnoreApiTest())
```